# Image preview does not work in IE and Firefox fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

below code is working fine for Chrome but not for IE and FireFox. Please let me know if I am missing something in below.

```
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <input type="file" id="profileimgload" name="profileimgload" onchange="PreviewImage();" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />    
</div>
<img src="../../images/static/default_images/user_default.png" id = "uploadImageBoxImg" width="150" height="150" />

<span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" align="center" onClick="addprofileimage()" title="change profile picture">upload</span>
</div>
```

javascript

```
    //profile image upload
function addprofileimage()
{
    $("#profileimgload").click();
}

function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("profileimgload").files[0]);
    alert("inside preview 2");
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        $("#uploadImageBoxImg").attr("src", oFREvent.target.result);
        //document.getElementById("imageHiddenField").value = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

Comment: do you see console in ie? some errors?

Answer (score 0):

First of all older versions of IE (9 and lower) don't support File API...

Also you better use `oFReader.onloadend` event instead of onload.

```
oFReader.onloadend = function () {

    $("#uploadImageBoxImg").attr("src", oFReader.result);

}
```

Here is some useful documentation about [File Reader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function PreviewImage() {
        var funcs = [];
        var documentos = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
        var tamanio = documentos.files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
            funcs[i] = (function(index) {
                return function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("uploadPreview" + index).src = event.target.result;
                };
            })(i);
        }
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        for (var k = 0; k < tamanio; k++) {
            oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(documentos.files[k]);
            oFReader.onload = funcs[k];

        }
```